# Parse this html table regex

Tags: html, regex

I have two related questions:

I have the following html text:

`<td style="work" class="sort"> 1500 </td>`

I would like to parse the `1500`, preferably with no spaces around it, although I could always trim after.

I'm testing on regex101, and here is what I have so far:

`>.*?<\/td>`

It returns to me back:

`> 1500 </td>`, which is close to what I want. I mean I can just manually parse this after, but I would prefer to only have `1500` back.

---

Second question:

If I have the following html text:

`<td style="work"> <a class="link" href="/img"> Lake </a> </td>`

How can I parse this to get back `Lake`? If I use the regex `>.*?<\/a>`, I would get back

`> <a class="link" href="/img"> Lake </a>`, which is more than I want.

Comment: I dont understand the downvote. I asked a reasonable question, provided my thoughts, and illustrated the problem

Comment: It's just match in javascript. 

`x = '<td style="work" class="sort"> 1500 </td>'`

`x.match(/>.*?<\/td>/g)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/m71Tm6/1

Comment: @MDR capturing only **word charactors** !

Answer (score 0):

Use **Parentheses** for Grouping and Capturing

First check for pattern `>(.*?)<\/a>`  . If that doesn't match,
check for `>(.*?)<\/td>`

However it doesn't recommend to parse HTML using Regex. Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/12731030).

**Edit:** MDR's solution (`^.*?> (\w+) <.*?$`) works if you want only to capture [word charactors](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp).